# macOS 'wchar.h' File Not Found

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

Under OS X 10.9.5 using XCode 6.0.1 I am running into the following issue when I try to run `make` from the terminal:

```
fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
```

This issue was not happening prior to a recent upgrade to Mavericks.

Comment: Hello from Google. [This is the answer you're probably looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/510036) if you upgraded to Mojave recently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First ensure that the latest XCode is installed. Next, we need to install/fix/update Command Line Tools. To do so, run

```
xcode-select --install
```

Previously, XCode expected it's active developer directory to be located at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

but the latest Command Line Tools is installed to

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

so we need to switch where XCode is looking. To do so, run

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

And that should be it. These steps solved the issue for myself and two coworkers.

Comment: Does not work for me. I can see that wchar.h file is located on /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h and it should be found. There is no such file in command line tools folder (and deeper there)

Comment: I had the same problem, but with string.h  The solution for me was to delete "by hand" (with Finder) all output directories. The problem was that some old output files referenced out-of-date XCode paths. After I deleted all the output files, the problem was solved

Comment: @peter70 Where are the output files you're referring to located? I encountered this issue with a Qt build, and I have no idea where to start looking for those output files.

Comment: @Piotr99 If I remember correctly, they were the normal output files, in the output directory I specified (in Qt Projects Build Settings)

Comment: @peter70: Thank you for your comment, it was the same for me.

Answer (score 54):

- My error was similar to yours which said string.h not found, I solved it by running this command:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

I think that the problem is that for macOS Mojave users, the headers are no longer installed under /usr/include by default.

Comment: This works in combination with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185979/2652054

Comment: No Packages folder under /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/.only have following folders `Library`, `SDKs` and `usr`

Answer (score 14):

Adding on ssell's post and peter70's comment, I also still had issues after installing xcode command line tools again, and switching the xcode active developer directory.  I was using CMake, and so deleted the debug/release folders which had existing Makefiles referencing out-of-date locations on Mojave.  So for future problem resolving, after running the commands from ssell's post:

`xcode-select --install`

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

I believe if you've installed the command line tools by installing Xcode itself, you may also need to agree to the licence with `sudo xcodebuild --license`.  I don't think this is necessary if you used the prior `xcode-select` command.

Then also delete generated build scripts.  If using CMake, delete the `cmake-build-debug` and `cmake-build-release` directories (your names may vary)

Answer (score 13):

Deleting all the generated files and restarted the compilation worked for me. It was suggested in this link:

https://discourse.brew.sh/t/solved-scan-build-from-llvm-7-0-seems-broken-on-macos-mojave/3151/14

Comment: Works for me! (Here is my case: seems that I firstly let cmake generated those files (months ago), then update the mac version, then try to make / cmake again.)

Comment: It works for qt6, and I deleted pro.user file.

Comment: Regenerating from CMake and then ninja was not enough. Deleting the CMake-generated files also worked for me. I guess mine were too old. I wish CMake were smart enough to delete the old cache.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting all the generated files, like @Alfredo Morales Pinzón.
If you use cmake, so you need to delete the work dictionary which is "cmake-build-debug" and regenerated the "cmake-build-debug".

Comment: Works for me! (Here is my case: seems that I firstly let cmake generated those files (months ago), then update the mac version, then try to make / cmake again.)

Answer (score 1):

`xcode-select --install worked for me.`

additionally if you're using visual studio code and your intellisense acts weird -

1. make a folder called `.vscode` in your project root.
2. install vscode extension call C/C++ by microsoft
3. create the `c_cpp_properties.json` file and paste the below contents

`project_dir > .vscode > c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "macOS",
        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks", "/Library/Frameworks"],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: up this. I guess the basic error comes from a wrong compiler path from vscode settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you update all symbols files which have references to the `wchar` after updating `xcode`. For me full cleaning build directory has worked

Answer (score 0):

If it happened after update Xcode you need (Apple WTF?) download and install Command Line Tools for Xcode manually from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode

Or using terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

Restart and maybe clean build cache (delete `cmake-build-debug`) before run your project.

I guess it's needed every time after update Xcode for all major program update

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the path of compiler gets changed after update or other advancement maybe xcode reinstallment.
I have tried everything that was given on every site sadly none worked.

I figured out that many issues cause this .

But then what worked for me is unlinking gcc.
I had also installed gcc from homebrew earlier.
Just unlinking it worked for me.
So if you are also one of the few who has installed gcc from homebrew then

brew unlink gcc

should be sufficient to get it off your default path, so you'll be back to Xcode's default gcc (assuming you have that installed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS Ventura. I've been struggling with this for hours. Setting symbolic links was the only solution that worked for me. Here is it https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349403/11822798.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and fixed by adding

```
"-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

in `tasks.json` under `args`