# OS X El Capitan ‘wchar.h’ File not Found

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, clang, osx-elcapitan

Under `OS X v.10.11.6` using `XCode 8.0` (immediately after the installation of `XCode`) I tried to run various example programs from Qt. The next error message appears:

> error: 'wchar.h' file not found

I read
[macOS 'wchar.h' File Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/os-x-mavericks-wchar-h-file-not-found) 
but it seems the answer does not solve my problem (so far).