# MacOS clang via Homebrew broken under Mojave `wchar.h`

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm, macos-mojave

Unsurprisingly the new update of OSX Mojave broke my llvm installation in Homebrew, these are the steps I tried:

```
xcode-select --install # Complained, so I installed commandLineTools from here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
xcode-select -p /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install # Now says installed
sudo xcodebuild -license # Fails, as it says I only have CommandLineTools installed in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools not xcode

# Try something else (all versions)
brew uninstall --force llvm
brew install llvm # yay v7 how exciting

# Only it still don't work
clang++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp -o f
In file included from foo.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas? The first half of the things I tried I found online but mostly for older updates of MacOS, maybe Mojave broke things in a new and unpredictable way.

Comment: While the question is a dup, the answer is NOT a dup and the only one that works.

Comment: Last part here https://arsbrevis.de/ helped me

Comment: See ['wchar.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308320/14170429)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved it (very dirty but has worked for a long time):

1. Disabled SIP on my Mac
2. Symlinked `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include` to `/usr/include` as is expected in POSIX environments.
3. Re-enabled SIP.

Now I got to make a note to re-do this everytime a new OSX update comes out. This has not broken anything wrt Xcode, clang (from brew) etc so I'll keep it. Be advised though, this might break your stuff.

Comment: This worked for me but I really don't like it. I have to reboot in recovery mode and run a script every time I update now. Recovery mode is really unpleasant. Three finger drag is disabled. The mouse sensitivity is slightly lower. Key repeat is disabled. Many command-line tools don't seem to be in my PATH so I had to use an absolute path to access micro (successor to nano).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue of the latest macos. Try to set this environment variable, it must fix this issue.

```
export LIBCLANG_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

Comment: Well known where? Because I’ve been looking for a solution since yesterday. Also why downvotes it’s not intuitive at all!

Comment: I got this solution from my college. Our company forbids upgrading macos till Mojave due to having SDK and clang issues on this macos.

Comment: I see, also unfortunately that did not work for me I'm still gettting the same error despite putting the envvar in my bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

I did something dumb but it did fix the problem... Not sure if it will work for your computer though.

Here is what I did: 
I originally installed c++ using Homebrew on my MacBook on Mojave... so I had to manually install the Xcode CommandLineTools using the installer found at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` . Then I copied the "c++" folder contents from to folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1` to the folder where I want the missing file to be, at `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0` , while replacing files with the same names.

The trick worked, since now the missing file **"wchar.h"** is right where it should be... I could have simlinked, in hindsight. Cheers!