# can not build cpp using clang pre-built binary: file wchar.h not found

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I am using MacOS 10.15. Since the clang shipped with MacOS does not include `clang-format`. I installed another pre-built clang binary from [here](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#10.0.0). I have added the binary file path to my `PATH` variable.

```
export PATH="$HOME/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin:$PATH"
```

I tried to compile a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

using the following command:

```
clang++ hello.cpp -o hello
```

I got the following error:

```
In file included from hello.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:214:
In file included from /Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
/Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:118:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I found that `wchar.h` bundled with this pre-built package is in the following directory:

```
/Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/include/c++/v1/
```

So I added the `-I` flag:

```
clang++ -I /Users/jdhao/tools/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/include/c++/v1 hello.cpp -o hello
```

The error still persists.

If I use `clang++` shipped with MacOS, I have no problem compiling the source code:

```
# the following works without any error
/usr/bin/clang++ hello.cpp -o hello
```

I have seen post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342411/wchar-h-file-not-found), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104473/macos-clang-via-homebrew-broken-under-mojave-wchar-h), but the solutions do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You got `clang-format` improperly. Reset the system to the state before you installed another pre-built clang binary. Then use Homebrew to install clang-format

```
brew install clang-format
```

clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin is not suitable to your Mac. It depends on system frameworks that are not available, so you get the error finding `wchar.h` in a system framework. When you install clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin you ignore framework dependencies. Homebrew will care about dependencies.