# gcc and g++ stopped working after I upgraded to macos 12.2.1

Tags: c++, macos, g++, macos-monterey

After I upgraded my macos to 12.2.1, I am getting weird errors when I run g++ (also with gcc). Here is a sample:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:38,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
             from try1.cpp:2:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

I tried the following solutions, but none of them have worked so far:

(A) updated xcode: (same result)

```
xcode-select --install
```

(B) based on solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602):

```
export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1
```

This only changed the line number of the error, now I get this error message:

```
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95,
             from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:214,
             from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37,
             from try1.cpp:2:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
  119 | #include_next <wchar.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
```

When I searched for this file, I saw this is at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h
```

For your reference, this is the simple code that I am trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

   string str1 = "Hello";
   string str3;

   // copy str1 into str3
   str3 = str1;
   cout << "str3 : " << str3 << endl;
}
```

And my xcode version is:

```
Xcode 13.2.1
Build version 13C100
```

(I get similar problems when I run gcc, example: "_stdio.h not found")

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do I need to uninstall and re-install xcode and gcc?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: If you instead `export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include` and `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1` , do you still get the same error?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: yes, exactly the same error as with the export of CPATH

Comment: Ok, it was worth a try. If you also add `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include`, same thing I guess?

Comment: There is a lot of answers on SO. One of them should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342411/wchar-h-file-not-found

Comment: @TedLyngmo: yes, same error with that also

Comment: @273K: many of those answers refer to SDK. Are those for some app development packages? Should I try different paths for normal (not app building) compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 12.2.1. I created a very simple file:

```
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
}
```

And I compiled with:

```
g++ Foo.cpp --std=c++17 -o Foo
```

It compiled without any errors. For me, this is a brand new machine (I literally got it yesterday). I have none of the env vars included you list.

I get the g++ in /usr/bin/g++. However, it's not the gnu compiler. It's Apple's clang. (g++ --version). clang version 13.0.0.

If you upgraded and did the xcode thing, then you might be in a weird mode that you have real g++ in your path, but it's pointing to weird shit. If you need g++ and not clang, then maybe remove and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced that when my Mac decided to auto update the XCode version. I solve it by updating (reinstalling) XCode command line tools.

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Reference: [How to update Xcode from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line)

Comment: Yes, looks like that is the only solution. I also reinstalled my brew, just to be on the safe side.