# After Mojave update problems with "make": fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found

Tags: macos, makefile, macos-mojave

After my Mojave update I get an error when runing "make" from the terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
```

The file wchar.h IS located in that directory but cant be found.

I had this problem once after an earlier Macos update but it could be solved with..

[macOS 'wchar.h' File Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found)

But this time nothing works. I already reinstalled xcode 10 and xcode-selected and also switched to the new folder with..

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

It is still searching for wchar.h in the folder

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/

Any Ideas for this!!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure whether it's a universal solution, but setting `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to the following did the trick for me:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you but did not work for me. Even more other errors.