# How can I solve this error on macOS catalina?

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile a Cpp program with g++ compiler, but I am getting this error:

```
Yuliam-MBP:Documents yuliamosh$ g++-9 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic vector.cpp -o vector
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/ostream:3,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from vector.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/include/c++/9.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Have you got Xcode installed with command line tools ? Can you compile a simple HelloWorld Programm ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that successfully. But unable to solve the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "wchar.h" was not found.

I would suggest to follow the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found) thread.

Comment: I am getting error for both wchar.h and also for stdlib.h.

Comment: have you tried the suggestions from the comments in that thread. That seems to be your exact problem. Also I would compile with clang on MacOs

Comment: I had already tried things related to that thread as well. nothing seems working. I deleted old object files and complied again. Tried installing packages as well. And also I ran all the commands suggested there as well.

Answer (score 0):

**INSTALL**
`xcode-select --install`

THEN SWITCH TO NEWLY INSTALLED TOOLS
 `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

You might need to reset the default location of the compile tools:

`xcode-select --reset`

> These are the usual fixes. **SADLY, NONE OF THEM WORKED FOR ME!**

**THIS IS WHAT WORKED FOR ME:**
[Homebrew Solution](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/clang-can-no-longer-find-usr-include-header-files-fatal-error-stdlib-h-file-not-found/4523)

Comment: what exactly you did to fix the problem??  Below mentioned one? if so I am unable to follow the steps can you please elaborate it please.                                                                       
 "-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk to CPPFLAGS..."??

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue? need help, please.

Comment: I literally posted the link that worked for me lol. Check it out!