# Can't compile c++ program using gcc on Mac after updating to Monterey

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, macos-monterey

*Update:
Regarding the similar question [macos-wchar-h-file-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found), the command line tool switch(xcode-select --install) doesn't exist anymore.

I am running on macOS Monterey system and I am trying to compile a simple hello world .cpp file using the g++-11 commend (I installed gcc using homebrew), I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
```

I tried two compile commands:

```
g++-11 -c hello.cpp -o hell.o 

g++-11 -std=c++11 -c hello.cpp -o hell.o
```

Here is the file I am trying to compile:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Test
//
//  Created by Jiali Zhu on 1/9/22.
//

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOS 'wchar.h' File Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found)

Comment: @drescherjm I saw that question and tried the things suggested in the answers there. My problem does not seem to be related to xcode's command line tool.

Comment: Please include the compile command you used!

Comment: @RichardBarber I have made edits to the question. Thank you for the suggestion. Sorry that this is my first time posting questions here.

Comment: Command likely needs `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: or, `-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk` or something like it with the proper target macos version you have installed.

Comment: I believe you're using brew installed gcc, which should have `wchar.h` in `Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/tr1`. If not, you could try to reinstall or check gcc's include path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem and in my case the problem was outdated
command line developer tools.

I found out it by running

```
$ brew doctor
...
Warning: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.1.
```

I tried to update them via `softwareupdate -l`, however this did not give me any update information.

So removed them and reinstalled with `xcode-select --install`.

After this `g++-11` stopped giving me an error about this header.

Now `brew config` tells me that I have `CLT: 13.0.0.0.1.1627064638`

P.S.

Also I started the xcode and it asked me whether additional components need to be installed and I said yes.

Comment: For me remove and re-install did NOT fix the "wchar.h: No such file..." for g++11 compilation. So I suppose you did something else that affected the problem?

Comment: What does your brew doctor tells you? Does it give you the error
```Warning: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install
```