# How to change Clang version(or InstalledDir) on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, clang

On MacOS terminal, when I run this command:

```
$ which clang
```

I got:

```
clang version 10.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin
```

But,I have another clang version on my Mac, the directory is:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang
```

So, how to change my current clang directory (/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin) to a new clang directory
(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang)?

and I am wondering that why my clang is  defaulted to install in Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the brew command on macOS. https://brew.sh/

It's better to use it to install clang because the command line tools version of clang's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

`export PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:$PATH` should work. You could add it to your run config file, whichever shell you're using.

Comment: Thanks.  I have already added this line to ./zshrc as well as ./bash_profile. Then I got this:
`
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
` It works. But the final problem I want to solve with is : I can't use command 'clang' to compile my .cpp files. For example, 'clang hello.cpp -o hello',  the result is:
` 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~

Comment: Thanks. I have already added this line to ./zshrc as well as ./bash_profile. Then I got this: <br/>Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) <br/>Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0 <br/>Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin<br/>

Comment: you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found)'s answers useful for your case ?

Comment: Else just install clang through `brew` and update to latest version

Comment: should i uninstall my clang first? Seems that I have 3 versions of clang, it's terrible.

Comment: Yes, one version is enough haha