# XCode standard C++ headers suddenly not found before installing OSX update

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

I have a C++ project that have been compiling fine until now, I did not install any update of my system or XCode but I get this error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:123:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found

This file does exist on my system, so I suppose it's the CMake env paths that are no longer set up properly in the console?
**Edit:** if I clean my build dir and regenerate the whole CMake project, it is working again, but I still find this behaviour very unpleasant.

This has happened just when there was an available update for MacOS 13.0, and probably XCode updates going with it. But I did not install any of them yet, and my compilation is already broken.
What is happening so that the dev env is changed anyway?
I remember I had likewise issues last time there was an OS update.

Is any configuration needed to "secure" a dev env on MacOS?
Are all OS updates going to screw my XCode includes etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185978/macos-wchar-h-file-not-found, although that is quite old (OS X 10)

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed the same issue, I will see how it applies to the last OSX version but there are many useful informations.